# Complex Case Statement in SSIS Expression

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, msbi

Trying to re-write Case statement in SQL to SSIS Expression.

```
Case When  ADate is Null and BDate > DateAdd(DD,120,CDate) then 'ABC'
    When  ADate is not Null and BDate > ADate then 'CVA'
Else '' 
End
```

Is this even possible to re-write as SSIS Derived Column Expression.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's just ugly.

```
(ISNULL( @adate) ==TRUE && @bdate > DATEADD( "DAY", 120, @cdate ))? "ABC" : (ISNULL( @adate) ==FALSE && @bdate > @adate)? "CVA" : ""
```

I declared the column names as variables to test the syntax.  Remove the @ symbols for your version.

Here is the relevant MS documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx

And many examples:http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/6/8/nested-conditional-operators-in-an-ssis-derived-column.html

Comment: Please post the error message and your version of the code.  As a reminder, the code is case-sensitive.